# Why does my calculator produce two seemingly different equations?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, calculator

Or maybe there are two ways this equation can be answered and the different inputs correspond to the calculator's understanding.

Anyway, I have a TI-36x Pro

and when I enter *.0179/1x10^-10* I get *1.79x10^-12*

But when I enter .0179/10^-10 I get 179000000 or 1.79x10^8

I suspect that when have to enter a number and it must be divided by a number in exponential notation, I cannot enter it as, for example, *1x10^10* but must enter as *10^10*.

Does this mean that if I have to divide something say 8x10^-5 I should enter it as 80^-5?

Comment: 8x10^-5 doesn't equal 80^-5 so DON'T do that.  Don't worry about it.  Those answers are both the same even if they look different.

Answer (score 2):

The division is being evaluated first, then the multiplication, because when the operations have the same standing it goes left to right.  So in the first case it's dividing by 1, a non-op, and then multiplying by $10^{-10}$, whereas in the latter case it's dividing by $10^{-10}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculator interpret the first entry as

$$\frac{.0179}{1} \times 10^{-10}$$

and the second entry as

$$\frac{.0179}{10^{-10}}.$$

Hence, you get different answers.

Comment: Does this mean that if I have to divide something say 8x10^-5 I should enter it as 80^-5?

Comment: And can you direct me to a place where I can learn the coding on how to enter fraction and exponents in html? 

Something that gives a crap load of examples so I can learn by coping.

Like I learned that to make exponents I need dollar signs, $10^6$ but what do I enter for negative and double digit exponents?

Comment: what about introducing braces? 
$8 \times 10^{-5}$ and $80^{-5}$ are different, so you can't do that.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez No, because $8 \times 10^{-5} \neq 80^{-5}$. You should put parentheses around whatever is in the denominator.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez To type fraction $\frac{a}{b}$, I use \frac{a}{b} surrounded by dollar signs, to type $10^{-3}$ and $10^{20}$, I use 10^{-3} and 10^{20} surrounded by dollar signs. Keyword to google for, "mathjax".